# finding core dumps in public root

Tags: server

Am suddenly finding lots of core..xxx files dumped in the root of my site.
In devMode cant see any issues. Assume this is serious issue and memory dump?

Where to start? Logs have loads of stuff but nothing that gives me a clue to this.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't Craft log files.  I'd suggest contact your host and give them the files so they can look and see what's dumping them and what the root problem is.

Comment: haha I am the host with  server tech manager on hand. Its only happening on my craft installations. I noticed 3 dumps this morning and the craft logs show something weird. They show 2017/01/10 14:44:15 [error] [exception.CDbException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). Almost like its reading my local dev config instead of the staging config...

Comment: I have found the matching of host names to config sections in Craft to misbehave at times, and therefore be dependent on order.

Comment: @joomkit Just confused, I suppose. You said `core..xxx` files were dumped, but that error message looks like a Craft log entry.  Regardless, for that particular message, that's something that Craft/PHP/PDO will often return as an error message when it can't connect to the database (for whatever reason). It's a bit misleading, I agree.

Comment: Just had this happen again and went thru the logs - there is nothing in craft logs to indicate anything prior to the dump - I have seen funky behaviour from host names before so suspect it might be that or some random nginx cache issue.....once i solve i'll post back

Comment: Seems to have been resolved now. I cant offer much in exact solution other than that we upgraded to easyapache 4 (WHM/Cpanel) and it's stopped happening. Switched to php7 and tested on php5.6 and problem has disappeared. Happy and confused about it. thx